# Straight tube using tubegeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

how can I create a straight tube using TubeGeometry?

I can only find examples with curves.

Comment: Is it a cylinder what you're after?

Comment: Yeah it is a cylinder, upon further inspection of the documentation for the cylinder implementation theres a parameter for open ended cylinder.

All I did was create a cylinder that was open ended and then for the inside, I created another cylinder that was 1 less radius than the other one and flipped it so it wouldn't be emptiness when you look inside.

Comment: You could also set `mesh.doubleSided` to `true` to the first cylinder and you won't need the second one.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you mrdoob! This will save me some time and typing in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up looking at the documentation and there were extra parameters that allowed me to set the cylinder open ended or not.

As mrdoob said, i also set doubleSided to true so the inside of the cylinder is not showing blank.

Edit: sorry forgot to show how I did it using the parameters.

```
THREE.CylinderGeometry = function ( radiusTop, radiusBottom, height, segmentsRadius, segmentsHeight, openEnded )
```